# демон-скрипты на php

Tags: php

Стоит ли писать высоконагруженного демона на php? Много читал о том что этого делать не стоит, в php есть масса дар, например утечка памяти, т.е. переменные вовремя не удаляются из оперативной памяти, и когда она закончится демон умрёт. Но ведь php постоянно совершенствуется с выходом новых версий(php 7), исправили ли это там, и можно ли теперь писать демонов на этом прекрасном языке?
Буду рад если кто-нибудь поделится ссылочкой на хорошую статью об этом.

Comment: Используйте `socket`.

Comment: просто пишите и смотрите что происходит с памятью в вашем конкретном скрипте. если утечки есть, ищите в каких функциях они возникают и пробуете это как то вылечить. В принципе это касается любого языка